# Finding coefficients for a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose i have an equation that satisfies the following first order differential equation:

$$2x[f(x)]^2=e^xf(x)+e^xf'(x)$$

Is there a way to determine the coefficients of a higher order equation of the form
$$4x^2[f(x)]^3=C_0e^{2x}f(x)+C_1e^{2x}f'(x)+C_2e^{2x}f''(x)$$
and can it be extended to the 
$$(2x)^{n}[f(x)]^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^nC_ke^{nx}f^{(k)}(x)$$

I know that I can use substitution of the lower order into the higher order but this really only works on the smallest of the df's.  The technique would not be effective because the length of substitutions required using this "recursive" technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try the third power
\begin{align}
2xf(x)^3&=e^x\{f(x)^2+\tfrac12 (f(x)^2)'\}\quad|·2x,\quad\text{insert original equation}\\
4x^2f(x)^3&=e^x\left\{\left[e^x(f(x)+f'(x))\right]+x\left[e^x\frac{f(x)+2f'(x)+f''(x)}{2x}-e^x\frac{f(x)+f'(x)}{2x^2}\right]\right\}
\\
8x^3f(x)^3&=e^{2x}\left\{(3x-1)f(x)+(4x-1)f'(x)+xf''(x)\right\}
\end{align}
(Edit: Corrected coefficient of $f''$.)

---

One could also start by reformulating the equation in terms of $g(x)=e^xf(x)$ so that $$2xe^{-2x}g(x)^2=g'(x).$$

Comment: What about higher order without the plug and chug method?  Is there a way to find a, say, 7th order?

Comment: In the next step you multiply the original equation with $f(x)^2$ and insert on the right side the found expression for $f(x)^3$ and its derivative. Thus you can advance one degree at each time. I'm not sure, but there should be a way to employ generating functions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $+f''(x)$?

Comment: Yes and no. For some reason I was mentally taking the second derivative from the last term.